# Selecting a column and listing

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a homework question from an Oracle 11g course.

So the question requires me to write a query listing the program names and all the related courses within that program.

My tables are as follows.

```
program structure( program number, course code, course SEQ Number)
course(course code, course name)
program(program number, program name)
```

The result would look like

```
Program Name | Course Code
Biology| bio 101
biology| bio204
Biology| bio457
```

I missed the classes on join, so i'm a bit iffy with that area of the code. I know i have to select program number and course code from the program structure table and group by the program names but i'm not too sure how to get the inbetween...i believe i can use sub queries as well.

```
Select program_number, course_code
from program_structure 
where ??
group by program_name
??
```

Comment: The page at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp is a good place to start investigating `JOIN`.  There are many other good reference sources on the web that you can search for.

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be *perfect Oracle SQL, I think its actually good because it doesnt directly give you the answer, it is a HW problem after all. But an easy one since it looks like your class just started joins.
So this is more of the psuedocode:

```
Select P.program_name, PS.course_code  
FROM Program P JOIN ProgramStructure PS  
ON P.program_number = PS.program_number
```

This is essentially how you do a join between two tables.

Go ahead and add your group by clause to see what you get. 
[Here is a helpful link](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj35034.html)

Hope I was able to help :)

Comment: Your Answer could do with an `*` after the `*perfect`.

Comment: after a quick tutorial on JOINS and your little sample, this is what i came up with!  


`Select program_name, course_name  
From program_structure LEFT JOIN program ON program_structure.Program_Number = program.program_number  
LEFT JOIN course ON course.course_code = program_structure.course_code;`